# Membership probability for distributions over subsets

Tags: probability, distributions, subset

Fix a set $\mathfrak{A}$ and a probability distribution $\mathcal{D} : 2^\mathfrak{A} \to [0,1]$ defined over subsets of $\mathfrak{A}$. We can then ask "what is the probability $p(x)$ that a subset of $\mathfrak{A}$ drawn according to $\mathcal{D}$ contains $x$?", and easily compute
$$p(x) = \sum_{Y \subseteq \mathfrak{A}} \mathcal{D}(Y) \cdot \varepsilon(x,Y)$$
where $\varepsilon(x,Y) = 1$ if $x \in Y$, or 0 otherwise. We can get $p(x,y)$, $p(x,y,z)$, $\dots$ in the same way.

*Question 1*: The naive dimension-counting argument
$$2^{|\mathfrak{A}|} - 1 = \sum_{k = 1}^{|\mathfrak{A}|} {|\mathfrak{A}| \choose k}$$
suggests that $\mathcal{D}$ might be uniquely determined by $p(x), p(x,y), \dots$. Is this true (or even obvious in some way?)

*Question 2*: If so, are there any constraints on the $p$s beyond the bounds $p(x,y) \leq \min \{ p(x), p(y) \}$ and so forth, or can essentially any [0,1]-valued functions be used?

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to reinvent [measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_theory). One major problem it looks like you're going to run into is the existence of [non-measurable sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set). Basically, so long as $\mathfrak{A}$ is infinite, $2^\mathfrak{A}$ will be uncountable, and you won't be able to define a measure on every subset of $2^\mathfrak{A}$, at least under ZFC. This is why probability measures are usually defined on the Borel σ-algebra instead of on the full power set of ℝ.

Comment: @Kodiologist, please have a closer look; this isn't at all related to measure theory. For example, the values of $\mathcal{D}(X), \mathcal{D}(Y), \mathcal{D}(X \cup Y),$ and $\mathcal{D}(X \cup Y)$ can be assigned independently.

Answer (score 2):

After thinking about it some more, I have a partial answer. I'll slightly change the notation for $p$ to clean things up a bit, writing $p_\mathcal{D}(X)$ for the probability that a subset $Y$ drawn according to $\mathcal{D}$ satisfies $X \subseteq Y$.

From the definition of $p_\mathcal{D}$, $$p_\mathcal{D}(X) = \sum_{Y \supseteq X} \mathcal{D}(Y)$$

Then we can use Mobius inversion on the poset $(2^\mathfrak{A}, \supseteq)$ to get $$\mathcal{D}(X) = \sum_{Y \supseteq X} (-1)^{|Y| - |X|} p_\mathcal{D}(Y)$$
This answers question #1: $\mathcal{D}$ can indeed be recovered from $p_\mathcal{D}$.

That leaves question #2: what constraints must be placed on $p$ to ensure that $$\sum_{Y \supseteq X} (-1)^{|Y| - |X|} p(Y)$$ defines a probability distribution on $2^\mathfrak{A}$?  The condition that the distribution sums to 1 is equivalent to $p(\emptyset) = 1$.

But I am still not sure what conditions on $p$ are required to ensure that $\mathcal{D}$ only takes non-negative values.  Any ideas?